# How do I use Entity Framework with a RootObject DTO?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, entity-framework, dto

I'm trying to build a table or tables with mapping through Entity Framework, however, I'm having trouble doing it with the DTO file I've structured from an API that I'm using.

This is the DTO file that I'm using which I special pasted from POSTMAN for JSON data.

```
 public class AllRequests
 {
        public class Rootobject
        {
            public Operation operation { get; set; }
        }

        public class Operation
        {
            public Result result { get; set; }
            public Detail[] details { get; set; }
        }

        public class Result
        {
            public string message { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
        }

        public class Detail
        {
            public string requester { get; set; }
            public string workorderid { get; set; }
            public string accountname { get; set; }
            public string createdby { get; set; }
            public string subject { get; set; }
            public string technician { get; set; }
            public string isoverdue { get; set; }
            public string duebytime { get; set; }
            public string priority { get; set; }
            public string createdtime { get; set; }
            public string ignorerequest { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
        }
}
```

As you can see above, it's pretty hierarchical so it's not as straight forward as generating a table from a simple class file.

This is my `DbContext` file:

```
public class TransitionContext : DbContext
{
        private const string connectionString = (connection);

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }

        public DbSet<AllRequests> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

I've set the migrations which ran fine, there is a connection to my SQL Server. However, when I run the `Update-Database` command in the PM console, it won't work. The errors are not straight forward but they have me running around in circles, first it's set an ID key, then it's table relationships, but there's no good source material on how to do it.

Could anyone teach me how would I successfully implement this DTO through Entity Framework on my SQL Server? I'm guessing it would be utilising model creator but I'm still not sure how the process completely works in this context.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It does appear to missing some keys...

Comment: I can put [keyless] in the DTO file but there's still other problems with relationships it says and it won't build the table.

Comment: Post the exact error message..."it wont work"...well...won't work. Put it in the OP.

Comment: "Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Operation.details' of type 'Detail[]'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."

This is the error I get once I put [Keyless] on the DTO.

Comment: I didn't post it in the OP because I don't want to put too much information into the question. Preferably I'm looking for a guide or someone to put me in the right direction. Currently I'm not sure how to use EF with a DTO like the one I have there (with a RootObject). The errors I'm receiving are just too many that I know it's something to do with the model builder but I can't find any source material to assist with that in this context. 

I've been looking for hours.

Comment: @KyleAT `OP` is you - the original poster. Put all the information in the question. `I don't want to put too much information into the question.` you didn't put *enough* information. What you posted can't be mapped and would actually result in runtime errors the moment a DbContext was constructed

Comment: @KyleAT somethings's wrong, but you haven't posted enough information. EF doesn't deal with API DTOs, it deals with entities, tables and their mapping. What works for an API doesn't work for application classes or database tables. That `DbSet<AllRequests>` is meaningless, as there are *no* relations between the nested classes and enclosing class. It would make more sense if `AllRequests` was a namespace

Comment: `first it's set an ID key, then it's table relationships, but there's no good source material on how to do it.` on the contrary, every tutorial covers this. The reason there are so many errors is there's *no* configuration,  no relations between the classes, no `ID` properties. No conventions can be used to determine keys and relations

Comment: So there is no possible way I can get these DTO files on my server though Entity Framework? I just have a simple console application that has GET requests and saves them into that DTO file. I was hoping that EF could map and model the DTO file into a table so that the API data I receive when I run my application will eventually be able to save data to my database. 

If I show the full project that I've done, people won't read it. I'm trying to simplify it as best as I can, I've tried this before and had 0 response.

Comment: But regardless I appreciate the responses, it gives me something to think about, I might have to go back to the basics. I'm probably misunderstanding what Entity Framework does and using the wrong terminologies to explain my problem.

Comment: @KyleAT EF is a beast of sorts...What I think you need to do is remap that Get into an EF friendly class. Create your classes, code first, migrate..update. Do your GET and map that JSON back into the classes.

Comment: Okay thank you @ChrisCatignani I'll do this and go back to the basics. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @KyleAT Take a look at https://www.udemy.com/course/entity-framework-core-the-complete-guide-net-5/learn/lecture/19946596#overview 
This is by Bhrugen Patel who does a pretty good job on instruction IMO.  I think you can get it fairly cheap right now.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani Thank you, I'll give it a read, I've already been making progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try useing [NotMapped] like the error message suggests

```
   public class Operation
        {
            public Result result { get; set; }
            [NotMapped]
            public Detail[] details { get; set; }
        }
```

If you need that array...EF needs a way to navigate it..ie a key.

Comment: There are no keys, no relations, no configuration in that DbContext while the only "configured" class, `AllRequests`, contains nothing at all. This is just 1 problem among dozens - there's not even a `DbSet<Operation>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I said on the OP, I used special paste from POSTMAN from a GET API. This DTO that I'm using was created from that, and the GET requests work, so data is being stored into that DTO file. Which I'm then hoping to map and store into a Request table. I was hoping it would be able to generate a set of tables or a table hierarchy from that class file. I did explain this part.

Comment: @KyleAT: The most straightforward way to do that is to write the mapping yourself from the Operation DTO to first-class EF entities.

Comment: @KyleAT you tried to map a class that contains nothing - no fields, no properties, no inheritance relation to the nested classes. It doesn't matter where those classes come from. `AllRequests` is simply empty

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have mapped classes before in Entity Framework with just a standard C# class though, with no data or EF annotations, just a primary default Id key and numerous other keys. 

So I thought it would be as straight forward as that.

Comment: @KyleAT in this case you have no primary key at all. And the class you actually use contains *nothing*.  This is nothing like what you tried before. Create DbSets for the actual classes at least, not the empty `AllRequests`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is true, but when I did add a primary key this time it just created an Id key instead and that was it. But now after some research I realise why. I think I just misunderstood how EF works, since before I didn't attempt to do it with DTO's and API's. Thank you for the help, I'll try and do this the correct way.

Comment: @KyleAT what did you expect? *AllRequests is empty. It contains nothing at all*. You need to use the *other* classes and *completely ignore* `AllRequests`. Better delete it completely so you don't get confused going forward. If it contains any useful methods, make it a static class. *Definitely* extract the nested classes into their own files

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well when I deserialize my API into JSON data, it is actually storing the data into that DTO correctly. When I run debug mode I can see that in the process. 

But yes I'll have to take the nested classes out as you said. The trouble with that is, it will be difficult to make the API work, because that's the format it came in, it has to go through this process of RootObject -> Operation -> Details. Personally, I only need the details information anyway, but I need to use the RootObject and Operation process with it for the API to work.